# Problem trying to use st_remove_holes function

Tags: r, dplyr, geospatial, r-sf

I'm trying to remove the holes from a shapefile with the st_remove_holes function from the nngeo package, but even after run it, some holes still remain.

```
library(dplyr) 
library(sf)
library(nngeo) 
library(geobr) 

sf_use_s2(FALSE)
shape.muni <- read_census_tract(year = 2010, code_tract = 3304557) # download the shapefile
shape.muni <- shape.muni %>% 
 group_by(code_neighborhood, name_neighborhood) %>% 
 summarise(geometry = st_union(geom)) %>% 
 st_remove_holes()
```

The result is:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4y8RW.png)

But it should be:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XmRor.png)

Comment: This might be useful for you https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/609#issuecomment-357426716. The comment recommends looping through each `MULTIPOLYGON` and pulling out the first `POLYGON` each time using `st_multipolygon(lapply(my_polys, function(x) x[1]))`.

Comment: try `sfheaders::sf_remove_holes()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the help. This solves the problem:

```
read_census_tract(year = 2010, code_tract = 3304557, simplified = F)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).